# How to check if NSString begins with a certain character

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How do you check if an NSString begins with a certain character (the character *).

The * is an indicator for the type of the cell, so I need the contents of this NSString without the *, but need to know if the * exists.

Answer (score 470, accepted):

You can use the `-hasPrefix:` method of `NSString`:

**Objective-C:**

```c
NSString* output = nil;
if([string hasPrefix:@"*"]) {
    output = [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
var output:String?
if string.hasPrefix("*") {
    output = string.substringFromIndex(string.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this same method, but instead of `hasPrefix:@"word"` you check for multiple values stored in an `NSArray`? For example: `NSArray  *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];` ?

Comment: ^^ See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019660/check-if-nsstring-hasprefix-that-is-contained-in-nsarray

Comment: CFStringHasPrefix() can also be used on NSStrings due to "Toll Free Bridging".  The performance of CFStringHasPrefix() seems to be 2-3 times better (at least when using my data set).  So if you are using it in a performance sensitive area, you might want to try CFStringHasPrefix() instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
NSString *newString;
if ( [[myString characterAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"*"] ) {
     newString = [myString substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: You can't send messages to unichars, and they probably won't be equal to NSStrings.

Answer (score 8):

[hasPrefix](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-hasPrefix_) works especially well.
for example if you were looking for a http url in a `NSString`, you would use `componentsSeparatedByString` to create an `NSArray` and the iterate the array using `hasPrefix` to find the elements that begin with http.

```
NSArray *allStringsArray = 
   [myStringThatHasHttpUrls componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]

for (id myArrayElement in allStringsArray) {
    NSString *theString = [myArrayElement description];
    if ([theString hasPrefix:@"http"]) {
        NSLog(@"The URL  is %@", [myArrayElement description]);
    }

}
```

`hasPrefix` returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string matches the beginning characters of the receiver.

```
- (BOOL)hasPrefix:(NSString *)aString,
```

parameter `aString` is a string that you are looking for
Return Value is YES if aString matches the beginning characters of the receiver, otherwise NO. Returns NO if `aString` is empty.

Answer (score 5):

As a more general answer, try using the hasPrefix method. For example, the code below checks to see if a string begins with 10, which is the error code used to identify a certain problem.

```
NSString* myString = @"10:Username taken";

if([myString hasPrefix:@"10"]) {
      //display more elegant error message
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`characterAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:). If the first character is an asterisk, use [`substringFromIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex:) to get the string sans '*'.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *stringWithoutAsterisk(NSString *string) {
    NSRange asterisk = [string rangeOfString:@"*"];
    return asterisk.location == 0 ? [string substringFromIndex:1] : string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Another approach to do it..**

May it help someone...

```
if ([[temp substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
  //starts with http
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help? :)

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:

Just search for the character at index 0 and compare it against the value you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This nice little bit of code I found by chance, and I have yet to see it suggested on Stack. It only works if the characters you want to remove or alter exist, which is convenient in many scenarios. If the character/s does not exist, it won't alter your NSString:

```
NSString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"YOUR CHARACTERS YOU WANT TO REMOVE" withString:@"CAN either be EMPTY or WITH TEXT REPLACEMENT"];
```

This is how I use it:

```
//declare what to look for
NSString * suffixTorRemove = @"&lt;/p&gt;";
NSString * prefixToRemove = @"&lt;p&gt;";
NSString * randomCharacter = @"&lt;/strong&gt;";
NSString * moreRandom = @"&lt;strong&gt;";
NSString * makeAndSign = @"&amp;amp;";

//I AM INSERTING A VALUE FROM A DATABASE AND HAVE ASSIGNED IT TO returnStr
returnStr = [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:suffixTorRemove withString:@""];
returnStr = [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:prefixToRemove withString:@""];
returnStr = [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:randomCharacter withString:@""];
returnStr = [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:moreRandom withString:@""];
returnStr = [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:makeAndSign withString:@"&"];

//check the output
NSLog(@"returnStr IS NOW: %@", returnStr);
```

This one line is super easy to perform three actions in one:

1. Checks your string for the character/s you do not want
2. Can replaces them with whatever you like
3. Does not affect surrounding code

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* expectedString = nil;
if([givenString hasPrefix:@"*"])
{
   expectedString = [givenString substringFromIndex:1];
}
```