# Wildcard URL's in `isEqualToString`

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, wildcard

So I have a method that checks URL's and will only allow specific URL's to be loaded in the web view.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([full isEqualToString:@"http://cheese.com/example1"] || [full isEqualToString:@"http://cheese.com/example2"]
        || [full isEqualToString:@"http://cheese.com/example3"]
        **|| [full isEqualToString:@"http://cheese.com/*"]**

        ) {
        NSLog(@"URL is %@, good to go!", full);
        return YES;
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"URL is %@, not going to load.", full);
        return NO;


}
```

My question is, in the third example `http://cheese.com/example/*` I'm trying to load everything that may pop up in place of the `*`. It is different every time. Is there a certain symbol or any way to have it load anything past the / in a couple of these checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[full hasPrefix::@"http://cheese.com/"]` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use hasPrefix on NSString

```
[full hasPrefix:@"http://cheese.com/"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to check if NSString begins with a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503436/how-to-check-if-nsstring-begins-with-a-certain-character)

Is a prefix check enough? This would allow you to just check the start without worrying about the rest of the string .