# Check if NSString hasPrefix that is contained in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, prefix

I have this `if` statement to check if a URL starts with a prefix:

```
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://example.com/";

NSString *currentURL = @"http://example.com/confirm";

if( [currentURL hasPrefix:[baseUrl stringByAppendingString:@"confirm"]] ){

    // True, so do something...

}
```

I would like to modify the `hasPrefix` part of my `if` statement so that it returns true if `currentUrl` is appended by **ANY** of the values in my `NSArray` shown here:

```
NSArray *pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"confirm",@"products",nil];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just iterate through your pages array and set a boolean flag if any of the terms exist

```
//
//  customstring.m
//
//  Created by rbertsch8 on 8/2/13.
//
//

#import "customstring.h"

@implementation customstring

-(bool)hasPrefixArray:(NSArray*)array withbaseURL:(NSString*)baseUrl
{
    bool hasprefix = NO;
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count] || hasprefix == NO; i++)
    {
        hasprefix = [self hasPrefix:[baseUrl stringByAppendingString:[array objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    return hasprefix;
}

@end
```

Now in your code do the following:
    //import your custom string file
    #import NSStringPrefix.h

```
NSStringPrefix *customURL = yoururl.com
NSString *baseUrl = baseurl.com
NSArray *yourarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"one", @"two"]

if([customURL hasPrefixArray:yourarray withbaseURL:baseUrl])
{
    //dowork
}
```

**UPDATE**

Define the variables in a global class.

```
#define companyOrSiteName @"Company X"
#define baseUrl @"http://www.example.com/" // Set base URL for site.
#define customUrlScheme @"example://" // Set custom URL Scheme for app.
#define openInModal [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"contact-us.php",@"products/",nil]
#define openInSafari [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"about",@"products/resources/download",nil]
#define twitterHandle @"Example" // Twitter username without the "@" symbol
#define kTrackingId @"UA-4564564-3" // Set Google Analytics iOS App Tracking code.
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that can be placed inline, as this will need to be used multiple times in different files. Is there a way to just modify the `hasPrefix` ?

Comment: in this case you will need to create a custom NSString class and override the hasprefix method (or make a new method like hasPrefixArray)

so make a new file -> objective c class - > subclass of NSString
we'll name it NSStringPrefix

in this class make a method:
    -(bool)hasPrefixArray:(NSArray*)array

Then you just add #import NSStringPrefix.h to your code and your currentURL variable will now be NSStringPrefix *currentURL

Comment: I understand creating the files, but can you put in a block of code demonstrating with an example? Thanks!

Comment: i edited my code above to show how you could implement a new hasprefixarray method into your custom NSStringPrefix class

Comment: So how would I use it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34701/discussion-between-rbertsch8-and-adam-d)

Comment: So which files do I need to create?

Comment: don't use a custom subclass, just add a category to `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *parts = [currentUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *name = [parts objectAtIndex:1];
```

After this you can check if the string name is a element in pages array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - How would I check if the string name is an element in the pages array? That's the question and your answer doesn't show that.

Comment: I meant by looping over the elements in the array and comparing them with the string name. Or alternatively u can use a NSDictionary to store the elements of the array to get a O(1) retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who want to avoid Carpal Tunnel Syndrome:

```
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://example.com/";
NSString *currentURL = @"http://example.com/confirm";
NSArray *pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"confirm",@"products",nil];
BOOL hasSuffix = NO;
[pages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* page, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  if([currentURL hasPrefix: baseUrl] && [currentURL hasSuffix: page]){
    hasSuffix = YES;
    stop = YES;
  }
}];
```

Your description sounds more like you are looking for a suffix, so there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, use following code

```
BOOL hasPrefixInArray = NO;

for(int i = 0; i < [array count] && hasPrefixInArray == NO; i++)
{
    hasPrefixInArray = [yourString hasPrefix:array[i]];
}

// check value here for hasPrefixInArray
NSLog(@"%d",hasPrefixInArray);
```